# Why the __device__ variable can't be marked as constexpr?

Tags: cuda

If I declare/define a variable like this:

```
__device__ constexpr int test{5};
```

I get an error

> error: A `__device__` variable cannot be marked constexpr

I can't find in the guide that restriction. The guide says:

> I.4.20.9. `__managed__` and `__shared__` variables cannot be marked with the
> keyword constexpr.

Moreover, my colleague with the same major compiler version (11) doesn't have this error.

What exactly causes this error on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CUDA 11.2, such usage was not allowed.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.2.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cpp11-device-variable):

> G.4.16.9. `__device__/__constant__/__shared__` variables
> `__device__`, `__constant__` and `__shared__` variables cannot be marked with the keyword `constexpr`.

In CUDA 11.4 (and beyond) such usage is allowed.

The change in behavior allowed by the compiler took place sometime between the CUDA 11.2.0 version and the CUDA 11.4.0 version.

Presumably the passing machine has a newer CUDA 11 version than yours.

Comment: That's exactly the case - I'm using 11.2 while my colleague 11.4. Thank you, that was my fault that I didn't check the guide version.